# 'Total Installs' in Android

Tags: android, google-play

In the android developer console, is 'total installs' based purely on the amount of downloads, or the amount of google users who have downloaded it? e.g. if I used the same google account and reinstalled dozens of times, would it make a difference?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said it counts users by account. That's why it says "(users)" behind the number of total installs. This number will only increase. In contrast "net installs" only counts the current installations on devices. So this number can vary and increase and decrease when users install or uninstall the app.

Comment: I have 51 total installs (according to the dev console) but the play store is still showing `10-50`. It has been over three days...Why has it not updated? Please let me know! :)

Answer (score 0):

Your total installs means the users numbers who installed your app. It is (in my opinion) in contact with Google account, so who have the same account, won't be increase your total installs number.

Hope is helps!

Comment: I have 51 total installs (according to the dev console) but the play store is still showing `10-50`. It has been over three days... Please let me know! :)